# batch learning with stereo images in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow

How to batch learning with `tf.readfile`?

```
for i in range(len(files_mask)):
    t_image_left = tf.read_file(files_left[i], name='read_fileimage_left')
    t_image_right = tf.read_file(files_right[i], name='read_fileimage_right')
    t_image_mask = tf.read_file(files_mask[i], name='read_fileimage_mask')
    t_left = tf.image.decode_png(t_image_left, name='decode_png_t_left', dtype=tf.uint8)
    t_right = tf.image.decode_png(t_image_right, name='decode_png_t_right', dtype=tf.uint8)
    t_mask = tf.image.decode_png(t_image_mask, name='decode_png_t_mask', dtype=tf.uint8)
```

Left and Right image and Mask batches should correspond to each other. Left top batch ought to be the left top batch in all images.

Is that possible with: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.train.batch`, but you also have to use a queue for filenames such as `tf.train.slice_input_producer`

```
filename_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([files_left, files_right, files_mask])
t_image_left = tf.read_file(filename_queue[0], name='read_fileimage_left')
t_image_right = tf.read_file(filename_queue[1], name='read_fileimage_right')
t_image_mask = tf.read_file(filename_queue[2], name='read_fileimage_mask')
t_left = tf.image.decode_png(t_image_left, name='decode_png_t_left', dtype=tf.uint8)
t_right = tf.image.decode_png(t_image_right, name='decode_png_t_right', dtype=tf.uint8)
t_mask = tf.image.decode_png(t_image_mask, name='decode_png_t_mask', dtype=tf.uint8
batch_left, batch_right, batch_mask = tf.train.batch([t_left, t_right, t_mask], batch_size=32, num_threads=1,
     capacity=500, enqueue_many=False,)
```

Comment: what is about having different images sizes? is it still possible?

Comment: filename_queue[0]: 'FifoQueue' Object does not support indexing.

Comment: images t_image_left and t_image_right as well t_image_mask are not the same. I already tried to switch off shuffle: `tf.train.slice_input_producer([files_left, files_right, files_mask], shuffle=False)`

Comment: `left = ['/home/test/dataset/middle_burry/training/Adirondack-imperfect/im0.png']
right = ['/home/test/dataset/middle_burry/training/Adirondack-imperfect/im1.png']
mask = ['/home/test/dataset/middle_burry/training/Adirondack-imperfect/mask0.png']
`
I am not sure

Comment: files_left, files_right, files_mask, should have same ordering of corresponding filenames. FOr example, files_left=[left_filename1, ....], files_right=[right_filenames1...] and files_maks = [mask_fileanmes1...], if this ordering is right, rest will be file.